# Bitwise AND operation on UInt8 enum

Tags: ios, swift, bitmask

Having the following enumeration

```
enum ColliderType: UInt8 {
    case Hero = 0b1
    case GoblinOrBoss = 0b10
    case Projectile = 0b100
    case Wall = 0b1000
    case Cave = 0b10000
}
```

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
    let combined = ColliderType.Hero.toRaw() | ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()

    // test 'combined' for the 'Wall' bitmask
    if (combined & ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()) { // Compliation error :[

    }
```

The error I'm getting is as follows

> Type 'UInt8' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Comment: the bitwise operator does not return a _boolean_ value for you, but – in your case – an `UInt8` instead, so you may want to compare that number with someone (`>0`) to get a boolean value eventually for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `combined & ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()` returns `UInt8` while `if` is expecting `BooleanType`.

```
if (combined & ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()) != 0 {
}
```

should work.

Comment: Actually, as of Xcode 6.1, it is `rawValue`, not `toRaw()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (combined & ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()) != 0 { // No Compliation error :[
```

The expression in an if statement must be Boolean. UInt8 isn't a boolean. Pointers are not booleans. Optionals are not booleans. Comparisons give booleans.

This enforces good coding practices; you are forced to write the code that you should have written in C or C++ or Objective-C.